# tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator assertion (osx 10.9)

Tags: macos, xcode8

When building an app via XCode 8, running the application on Mavericks (OSX 10.9), I receive a crash with the following error:

[image: Crash stack]

Apple does specifically mention this in the [XCode 8 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) with the following details:

> Asset Catalogs
>
> Applications compiled with Xcode 8 and a deployment
> target of iOS 7 may crash at launch with the following assertion:
>
> **Assertion failed: (maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator > 0 && tokenCount <
> maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator), function CUIRenditionKeyCopy, file
> /SourceCache/CoreUI/CoreUI-232.4/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m,
> line 185.**
>
> To work around this issue, update the deployment target to
> iOS 8.0 or higher, or add a single image to the asset catalog that has
> at least five attributes specified across the image set, such as:
>
> - scale (1x, 2x, 3x)
> - idiom (add iPad,iPhone, and a universal asset)
> - direction (left to right, right to left)
> - width/height class (any & compact, and so forth)
> - memory (add a 1 GB asset)
> - graphics (add a Metal
>   1v2 asset)
>
> It is not necessary to use the image in your code or to add
> all of these attributes. (27852391)

I've tried adding some 3x scaled images to the project, however I still receive the same exception. According to the documentation I only need to add one of those attributes to resolve the issue, however it does not seem to do the trick for me. Has anyone else run into this? Does anyone have any resolution?

Comment: You need to pick at least five of these attributes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I created a new icon and manually modified the json file to contain the following:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-17.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-18.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-39.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-38.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-48.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-49.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-19.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-20.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-37.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-36.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-50.png",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-51.png",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-21.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-22.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-35.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-34.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-52.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-53.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-23.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "filename" : "apple-16.png",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-33.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "filename" : "apple-32.png",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "apple-54.png",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "language-direction" : "right-to-left",
      "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "width-class" : "regular",
      "filename" : "apple-55.png",
      "height-class" : "regular",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

I do not actually use this icon anywhere. This sorted the issue. I have uploaded the icon [here](https://hankinsoft.com/IconFix.zip) if anyone runs into this issue and needs it.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this question and solution.

Comment: I have followed this solution but it still crashes Assertion failed: (tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator - 1), function CUIRenditionKeySetValueForAttribute, file /SourceCache/CoreUI/CoreUI-231.1/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m, line 136. Any solutions?

Comment: Try downloading the iconFix.zip file again. I just made an update to it and my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for this; I didn't want to require 10.10 if I didn't have to.

Comment: @Kyle +1 I had the same issue. I added your file and it seems to work. Do I have to add it to all of my asset catalogs or only to one?

Comment: @Tibidabo Just to one I believe. I made a separate asset catalog just for this fix.

Comment: @Kyle thanks, it makes sense as they all end up in a single file in the bundle

Comment: @Kyle I downloaded the `IconFix.zip` file which contains a folder named `Mavericks10.9.imageset`. Do I just drag the imageset folder into my Xcode project then resubmit the app to the App Store?

Comment: Why did you add 24 images if all that the workaround requires is adding single images with 5 attributes? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39840120/15809

Comment: @Mecki when I only specified five attributes, xcode was messing with them automatically and it stopped working. Specifying these 24 ensured it worked and xcode no longer messes with the files.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.  Just drag and drop imageset folder inside asset catalogue on Xcode editor. (D&D on the left pane where you usually add images in asset catalogue.)

Answer (score 3):

In my testing (also targetting `macOS 10.9`), this only occurred when building with Xcode 8 on `macOS 10.12`.

The crash at launch did not occur when building with Xcode 8 on `macOS 10.11.6`.

This might represent a quick work-around for some people, although Kyle's answer is definitive as per the Xcode release notes.  (I have not tested Xcode 8.1beta).

**Update**

Building with Xcode 8.1b2 on macOS 10.12, the behaviour is the same as with Xcode 8.0.  (Next test will be building on the 10.12.1 beta)

Comment: I had the same issue, I updated my apps for Touchbar and now they all crashing on 10.12.1 Kyle solution seems to work so far.